# cannot load sprites outside of replit using kaboomjs

Tags: javascript, html, game-development, kaboom

I have been working on a small game for fun these past few days using the kaboomjs library and it's working as expected when I'm writting and running it from replit, but if I try to run it using live server in vs code I keep getting

```
   failed to load ~/Desktop/Javascript/kaboom/sprites/baddie.kbmsprite
   Bt@https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:56:3338
   @http://127.0.0.1:5500/game.js:12:18
   J@https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:55:14756
   je/<@https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:56:396
   H/O<@https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:55:3425
```

this is an example of how the code I'm working with loads sprites:

```
kaboom({
  global: true,
  fullscreen: true,
  scale: 1,
  debug: true,
  clearColor: [0, 0, 0, 0.75],
});
loadRoot("~/Desktop/Javascript/kaboom/sprites/");
loadSprite("baddie", "baddie.kbmsprite");

scene("main", () => {
  const b = add([sprite("baddie"), pos(80,80)]);
});

start("main", 0);
```

It's just called in body of an HTML file

```
...
<body>
    <script src="https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm still figuring out JS so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try and add the extension (ie .png) at the end of your sprite?

I am using Wamp64 with vs code, i'll test  tonight to see if it works for me without the extension.

Comment: I tried to convert it to a .png and also tried loading from an imgur web address with no luck. The .kbmsprite is the file type that's exported from Kaboom's sprite builder on replit.

Comment: Could you link your project on replit? I'll try to replicate it

Comment: I tested your code in live server with a png and it works fine, i think you have an issue with your loadRoot. 

Right click your image in VS Code and click "Copy Relative Path" and add that in your loadSprite. You will need to change the dashes from \ to / and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Open directly index.html, live server gived me errors to

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/kaboom@2000.0.0-beta.24/dist/kaboom.js"></script>
```

Use this script inside HEAD tag.
Use .png file on sprites. Some error occurs for your sprites.
But easist way open REPLİT kaboom-ligth version and copy it directly to your VScode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ad-blocker extension in Google Chrome, try turning it off. While uBlock Origins blocks javascript codes in the background, it may also be blocking Kaboom.js. I solved the problem by turning off uBlock Origins.

[image]